# casperjs css selector exists but when click it raise "CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector"

Tags: javascript, casperjs

My code:

```
var search_selector = "a[href*='id=40076700745']";
casper.then(function(){
    if (this.exists(search_selector)) {
        this.wait(1000, function(){
            this.click(search_selector);
        });
    }
}
```

I use exists to check whether the selector exists, but when click it, casper give me an error.

Comment: Are you sure that the element is visible? Take a screenshot with `casper.capture()`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a semi-confirmed bug in PhantomJS: https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/378

The suggestions there are to use SlimerJS, or use an XPath selector. Now that PhantomJS 2.0 is released, I'd also suggest trying with that; perhaps Phantom 1.x had a bug with the `href*=` selector?

(Of course if you can reproduce it in SlimerJS too, make up a test case as shown in the above bug issue, and submit it as a casperJS bug.)

Comment: I haven't observed a bug with `[href*=value]`, but I know that PhantomJS has a problem with `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` selectors in some cases. This is also the reason of the problem of the issue you linked to.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, it is a shame the OP has not responded, as it would be good to know if this is the same bug, or a bug in casper, or just a typo in his own script.